# Create Windows application from an existing RDLC file

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have created a few reports that run on report server.

There was an evaluation period 180 days for report server and our company decided not to buy a license.

Is it possible
to utilize the RDLC files and create from them a few windows applications (winforms)?
If so, could you shortly describe the steps?

Comment: I'm inclined to say "no you can't" as you still need the reporting services back end to render the reports regardless of how or where you call them from!

Comment: You can build your report using ReportViewer Class & Data Objects as datasource. Then get the data and render it using .NET application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a ReportViewer control that can display rdlc reports from a server or local machine in a WinForms application. If that is a possible option you can work with, try looking into it. Here is some documentation from Microsoft on [Using WinForms ReportViewer Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver15).

There is a dedicated segment in the article above that talks about [Viewing reports in local processing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver15#viewing-reports-in-local-processing-mode)